# Does $fg=k$ and $f,k$ continuous imply $g$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Given $f: Y \to Z$ and $k: X \to Z$ continuous functions and given the fact that for a certain function $g:X \to Y$ we have
$$f(g(x))=k(x)$$
is $g$ necessarily continuous?

Comment: No.  Let $f$ and $k$ be constant functions.  Then $g$ can be anything.

Comment: What if we are not in a discrete topology?

Comment: Constant functions are continuous in any topology.

Comment: @user46944: The implicit operation in $fg$ is function composition, not multiplication.

Comment: Where operations on sets might not be defined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For a counterexample, suppose that $f$ and $k$ are constant functions.

Comment: My problem is on page 16 here:
https://esc.fnwi.uva.nl/thesis/centraal/files/f358061116.pdf
I do not believe that $\gamma_y$ "must be continuous"

Comment: Huh? We can take $g:Y \to Y$ to be any discontinuous function, and $fg$ will be continuous.